# how to make a table of parameters in a class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a parameter table and I want to model it in a class diagram. 
Should we put such a parameter table in a class diagram ?
What does this table represent exactly ? an enumeration or what ?
should i model it as an enumeration class ?

This is my diagram :

[image]

The table "Droit" is a parameter table.  Is my model correct ?

***Edit:***  The diagram is French. "*Profil*" and "*Droit*" means "Profile" and "Rights". "*Libelle*" means "Description".  And "*Ajouter*", "*Modifier*", "*Consulter*" means "Add", "Change", "View".

Comment: What? Can you please make complete sentences using a full stop and capitalize the right way? Then: what do YOU think, is a parameter table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your whole entity-control-boundary class diagram is about management of (user?) profiles.  It seems furthermore that your entity `Droit` represents the authorization rights that a `Profil` may have.

If these hypotheses are confirmed, I'd think that `Droit` should be fully part of this diagram.  It would be difficult to understand the structure of profiles and implement the controller methods without knowledge of this information.

The fact that you consider this table as a "parameter table" is not relevant here. The main question is not the importance of the class to the overall system but what you want to represent in your diagram.  If it's a zoom on profiles & authorisation management, you'll need it.  Of couse, would your model be focused on business classes, where such a a table wouldn't add to the understanding of the domain, would my answer be different.

Comment: You're reading the tea leafs here. This question needs a bit editing of the OP to be a question at all.

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes and no ;-) . **Yes**: you're fully right: the OP should clarify the question and translate the french terms.  **No**, I'm not completely reading in the tea leafs: the french text on the labels is pretty explicit about what is being represented, and I've worked with  enough french programmers asking me for a "table de parametres" (which is in fact not a parameter table but a table containing parameters, i.e. a configuration table).

Comment: In that case you have a domain knowledge I don't have ;-)

Comment: What I understood is if I have a "configuration table" I do not need to present it in my models! and modeling uml there is no difference between "normal" table and configuration table

Comment: sorry i didn't translate the frensh worlds ! but thanks @Christophe you did it :)